# Elasticsearch: reached maximum index count for current plan - status:500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch

Is there a Heroku cli command that will allow us to purge Elasticsearch indices?

This is the error that's returned which is causing our application to be non-functional:

```
reached maximum index count for current plan - status:500
```

Upgrading our current plan is not a feasible option due to being in stages at this time.
Please advise on how to cure this.

Comment: Which addon do you have installed?

Comment: Looks like you have [SearchBox](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/searchbox#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to simply [delete the indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) you want via a direct `curl` call. You first need to retrieve the URL of your ES cluster using the `heroku config:get` command and retrieving the appropriate variable:

If you've installed the [**SearchBox addon**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/searchbox):

```
SB_URL=$(heroku config:get SEARCHBOX_URL)
curl -XDELETE http://<SB_URL>/your_index
```

If you've installed the [**Found addon**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/foundelasticsearch):

```
FOUND_URL=$(heroku config:get FOUNDELASTICSEARCH_URL)
curl -XDELETE http://<FOUND_URL>/your_index
```

Last but not least if you've installed the [**Bonsai addon**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai):

```
BONSAI_URL=$(heroku config:get BONSAI)
curl -XDELETE http://<BONSAI_URL>/your_index
```

To test this out:

```
# create one index => OK
> curl -XPOST http://<***_URL>/your_index_1
{"acknowledged":true}

# create second index => OK
> curl -XPOST http://<***_URL>/your_index_2
{"acknowledged":true}

# create n'th index allowed by your plan => NOT OK
> curl -XPOST http://<***_URL>/your_index_n
{"error":"ElasticsearchGenerationException[reached maximum index count for current plan]","status":500}

# delete first index => OK
> curl -XDELETE http://<***_URL>/your_index_1
{"acknowledged":true}

# create n'th index again => OK
> curl -XPOST http://<***_URL>/your_index_n
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this, I found a non-cli solution.

1. log into Heroku
2. Select the "Resources" tab
3. Select "SearchBox Elasticsearch" (this is what I have installed, yours may be different)
4. Select Dashboard > Indices
5. Select the trash icon next to the index you want to delete

[image]

Comment: Glad you found it. I should have included that non-cli solution as well just for the sake of it but somehow got diverted ;-)